# SQL Error "Column count doesn't match value count at row" - yet I've checked that the number of columns equals number of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to set up a very simple SQL table that links to a bigger table - that table works fine but the second table constantly throws up the classic "column count doesn't match value count at row" error.

```
CREATE TABLE NonHeadlessDistro 
( 
Headless INT,
Proprietary INT,
EaseInstall INT,
SimilarTo VARCHAR(28), 
Gnome INT,
KDE INT,
LXDE INT,
XFCE INT,
MATE INT,
Cinna INT
);

INSERT INTO NonHeadlessDistro (Headless, Proprietary, EaseInstall, 
SimilarTo, Gnome, KDE, LXDE, XFCE, MATE, Cinna)
VALUES ('0','1','2','macOS','1','1','1','1','1','0'),
('0','4','4','Linux','1','1','1','1','0','0'),
('0','1','1','Windows','0','1','0','1','1','1'),
('0','2','2','Windows','0','0','1','1','0','0'),
('0','1','5','Linux','1','0','0','0','0','0'),
('0','1','4','Linux','1','0','0','0','0','0'),
('0','2','2','Linux','1','1','1','1','1','1'),
('0','3','5','Linux','1','1','1','1','1','1'),
('0','2','2','Linux','0','1','0','0','1','0'),
('0','1','2','Linux','0','0','1','0','0','0'),
('0','1','4','Linux' '1','1','0','0','0','0'),
('0','3','5','Linux','1','1','1','1','1','1'), 
('0','2','3','Linux','0','0','0','0','1','0'),
('0','3','5','Linux','1','1','1','1','1','1'),
('0','1','4','Linux','1','1','0','0','0','0'),
('0','5','2','Linux','1','0','1','0','1','0'),
('0','5','5','Linux','0','0','1','0','1','0'),
('0','5','4','Linux','1','0','0','0','0','0'),
('0','5','5','Linux','1','0','1','1','0','0'),
('0','2','3','Linux','1','1','1','0','0','0'),
('0','2','3','Linux','1','1','0','1','1','1'),
('0','2','3','Linux','0','0','1','0','0','0'),
('0','2','3','Linux','1','1','1','1','1','0'),
('0','2','1','Linux','1','1','1','1','1','1'),
('0','2','1','Linux','1','1','0','1','1','0');

SELECT linux_distro
FROM linux_distro LEFT JOIN NonHeadlessDistro
ON Headless
WHERE Headless ="0";
```

The exact error message appears as:

```
1 errors were found during analysis
1. 10 values were expected, but found 9. (near "(" at position 596)

MySQL said:
#1136 - Column count doesn't match count at row 11
```

Using online SQL error checkers, the problem appears to be within the INSERT INTO line, but I'm at a complete loss as to why one of the columns hasn't been acknowledged, as I've checked that the number of columns is equal to the number of VALUES. Reading up on other solutions for the error, the problem usually appears as a result of misplaced quotation marks, or missing values/columns, but for the life of me I can't see what is wrong with my SQL. It is most likely a incredibly simple mistake given that my initial errors with the first table were solved with adding a missing semi-colon. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm blind, I couldn't see my missing comma on line 11. However, I've opened up another can of worms - before MySQL was expecting 10 values and only found 9 values, but with the edit it now expects 11 values and it can only find 10. It now also affects all 24 lines from

```
INSERT INTO NonHeadlessDistro (Headless, Proprietary, EaseInstall, 
SimilarTo, Gnome, KDE, LXDE, XFCE, MATE, Cinna)
```

to the final

```
('0','2','1','Linux','1','1','0','1','1','0');
```

line, so I have the same error replicated 24 times. I'm guessing that there's probably a pretty fundamental problem here:

```
MySQL said:
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: Do you have any triggers set up to update another table such as an audit table? The schema of the audit table will also need to be updated.

Comment: Why are you inserting string values into integer columns?

Comment: Did you check out row 11, which is indicated in the error message? There is a comma missing in that row.

Comment: Mike - I have not done that

Comment: HoneyBadger - I haven't seemed to encounter any issues related to inputting the string values, at least as far as error diagnosis has led me to.

Comment: I don't think it is related to your current issue, but you should always use appropriate datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
('0','1','4','Linux' '1','1','0','0','0','0'),
```

has a comma missing